# The following packages have unmet dependencies (steam)

Tags: unity, steam, unity-control-center

When I try to open Steam, this appears in the terminal (i'm new to Linux):

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
[sudo] password for tomaz: 
  ...............................................................................................
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4)
unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not     going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not     going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
Press return to continue:
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: Probably your system is the 64Bit version. Check my answer, certain this is the solution. Anyway, comment your progresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please perform these commands before install Steam:

`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
 sudo apt-get update`